# Android Logs stop working throughout an activity

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

hi having an wierd issue was working and been Logging fine then all of a sudden all my logs have this error

The method v(String, String) is undefined for the type String

i have imported `import android.util.Log;` and it has benn working fine all day just suddenly decided that all my logs shouldnt work anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

That problem happens but that is nothing to do with android if other widgets working fine.

```
1. clean your project
2. close eclipse and re-open
```

.

These may help you.